# Continuous differentiable spline or function resembling floor

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, approximation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'd need any (real-valued) function (whatever meets the following description at least approximately) continuous and *thrice* differentiable everywhere (or twice if 3 not possible), with the following features.

Seen "by far, it would be resembling the *floor* function $\lfloor x \rfloor $, exactly equal to $j$ at each *positive integer* $j$, but then *slightly increasing* on the "horizontal" part and finally more suddenly raise to the next integer, so approximately doing  as follows. Let $\epsilon$ and $\alpha$ two arbitrarily *small* positive numbers given by the user. The function should be:

$j$  at any integer $j$  (I need only $j$ > 2, no need to consider negative integers)

increasing from $j$ to $j +\alpha$ near the the "horizontal part" of the floor, say approximately  over $(j, j + 1 - \epsilon$].

suddenly increasing (or non-decreasing), from $j + \alpha$ to $(j + 1)$, "near the step" of a floor function [say approximately over $[j + 1 - \epsilon, j+1$).

These pieces should be "joined" in such a way that the function is continuous and differentiable.
(Any function with the above characteristics will do: of course, the simpler the better: I need it for an iterative program)

**PS. added later**

If useful, I found this paper:
http://math.arizona.edu/~shankar/projects/TermPaper_Yilu.pdf

which has something which perhaps may come close (see pag. 10/11). But it is missing the increasing "horizontal" part.

Comment: What is the domain of your function? All $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, all positive real is fine. Actually, I just need the part for x > 2, if the constraint is useful.

Comment: I could give you a Spline if $x$ was limited between some minimum and maximum values.

Comment: Ah ok, then you can assume an upper bound. That is fine. Say the integer M (assume it very large, like 1000 digits or so).

Comment: So would a C / C++ / Python code do then (and if yes, which one)?

Comment: Well, the code will also print the function for you if that's what you want (you'll have to input your $M$ of course).

Comment: Well, any "formal" expression from which I can compute "by hand" (as another formal expression) the derivatives will be fine.

Comment: Second thought, for your requirement, the traditional Spline algorithm will yield a straight line, i.e., $f(x)=x$... So you'll also need to define a "midpoint" between every two integers in your domain. For example: $f(3.5)=3.1,f(4.5)=4.1,f(5.5)=5.1\dots$

Comment: @Pam -- The differentiability requirements do not preclude having linear pieces. Please see my answer, which will you curves that are as differentiable as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the function you need from an alternating sequence of linear pieces and polynomial pieces.

Over the interval $(j-1, j - \epsilon]$, you just use a straight line that increases from $j-1$ to $j -1+\alpha$. Call it's slope $m$, which we can calculate from $\epsilon$ and $\alpha$. In fact, $m = \alpha/(1-\epsilon$.

Similarly, over the interval $(j, j +1 - \epsilon]$, you just use a straight line that increases from $j$ to $j +\alpha$.

Now we need to fit in a polynomial piece $p$ that provides a steep upwards ramp over the interval $(j - \epsilon, j]$. The requirements are:
$$p(j - \epsilon) = j-1+\alpha \quad ; \quad    p(j) = j$$
$$p'(j - \epsilon) = m \quad ; \quad           p'(j) = m$$
A cubic polynomial has four coefficients, so you will be able to satisfy these four conditions. You could just assume $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, write down the four equations arising from the four conditions, and solve for $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$. This is the brute force approach; there are cleverer approaches using Hermite interpolation techniques, which give you the required curve immediately, without the need to solve a system of linear equations. See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline), for example. Applying the Hermite cubic formulae, we get
$$
p(t) = (m - \epsilon)(2t^3 - 3t^2) + mt + j - \epsilon \qquad (0 \le t \le 1)
$$
where $t = (x - j + \epsilon)/\epsilon$. You only have to do this once. Thereafter, you can get other polynomial filler pieces just by shifting this basic one to the left or right.

The curve constructed this way will be only once differentiable -- there will be discontinuities in the second derivative at all the joints. If you want a curve that's twice differentiable, you let $p$ be a quintic polynomial, and you add two more conditions that force it to mate nicely with the adjacent linear pieces:
$$
p''(j - \epsilon) = 0 \quad ; \quad p''(j) = 0
$$
To get a curve that's thrice differentiable, use a polynomial of degree 7, and so on.

Comment: That is, I think, exactly what I had in mind. The problem, I guess, is for me to actually put together the final expression for the thrice differentiable version and obtain the formal expression of it on the interval ($j$, $j+1$]

Comment: Well, that's a high-school algebra exercise. It's not too bad for the cubic case. For the quintic case, use a computer algebra system like Mathematica. It's just solving a linear system, so it's conceptually easy, but tedious for a human being (like me or you).

Comment: Or, I guess, for the "slope" part one could define a polynomial (or some other nondecreasing function) and then use the "steep upwards ramp" provided by the article linked, provided that the 2 pieces could be joint "smoothly" (so that the whole is differentiable) (?)

Comment: Yes, you can use a polynomial for the shallow slope part, if you want (though I don't know why you would). You just need its end slopes (the "$m$") to use in defining the steep ramp polynomials.

Comment: Yes, I'd like it not to contain any linear piece. Ideally, I would like be possible for the derivatives to be computed everywhere several times (before getting to 0).

Comment: OK. So decide what slopes you want to use at all the "joint" places, and then do the polynomial fitting on every segment, instead of alternating with linear pieces.

Comment: Yes, I guess conceptually it is exactly like you say, find a pair of high order polynomials and let some software "join" them. Or, somehow be able to correctly "join" 2 transcendental functions (like that in the article). Hmm, I guess I need to start learning Mathematica, unless some expert here has a solution argh!

Comment: See my edit. I added a link that gives an immediate explicit solution for the cubic case.

Comment: Yes, thank you: Hermite interpolator looks definitely more viable.

Comment: Added explicit formula for the Hermite cubic case.

Comment: Thank you! That's great: I will start playing with it.

Comment: The only reason I answered the question is because you used the word "thrice". It's nice to see some literacy on this site. The more typical butchery of my language is depressing.

Comment: LOL I use to visit the English Language twin site. Even though (as non-native speaker) I am often mistreated and marginalized by some nasty and bully users over there. People here are usually much nicer. Maybe because of the common love for math :-)

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, the traditional spline-computing algorithm will yield $f(x)=x$.

So you'll also need to define a "midpoint" between every two integers in your domain.

For example: $f(2)=2,f(2.5)=2.1,f(3)=3,f(3.5)=3.1,f(4)=4,f(4.5)=4.1$.

Here is a piece of Python code for any given number of points $(x_0,y_0),(x_1,y_1),...,(x_N,y_N)$:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = 1.0*x
        self.y = 1.0*y

def Spline(points):
    N   = len(points)-1
    w   =     [(points[i+1].x-points[i].x)      for i in range(0,N)]
    h   =     [(points[i+1].y-points[i].y)/w[i] for i in range(0,N)]
    ftt = [0]+[3*(h[i+1]-h[i])/(w[i+1]+w[i])    for i in range(0,N-1)]+[0]
    A   =     [(ftt[i+1]-ftt[i])/(6*w[i])       for i in range(0,N)]
    B   =     [ftt[i]/2                         for i in range(0,N)]
    C   =     [h[i]-w[i]*(ftt[i+1]+2*ftt[i])/6  for i in range(0,N)]
    D   =     [points[i].y                      for i in range(0,N)]
    return A,B,C,D

def PrintSpline(points,A,B,C,D):
    for i in range(0,len(points)-1):
        func = str(points[i].x)+' <= x <= '+str(points[i+1].x)+' : f(x) = '
        components = []
        if A[i]:
            components.append(str(A[i])+'(x-'+str(points[i].x)+')^3')
        if B[i]:
            components.append(str(B[i])+'(x-'+str(points[i].x)+')^2')
        if C[i]:
            components.append(str(C[i])+'(x-'+str(points[i].x)+')')
        if D[i]:
            components.append(str(D[i]))
        if components:
            func += components[0]
            for i in range (1,len(components)):
                if components[i][0] == '-':
                    func += ' - '+components[i][1:]
                else:
                    func += ' + '+components[i]
            print func
        else:
            print func+'0'
```

Here is how you can print the *Spline* function of the $6$ points in the example above:

```
points = [
    Point(2,2),Point(2.5,2.1),
    Point(3,3),Point(3.5,3.1),
    Point(4,4),Point(4.5,4.1),
]
A,B,C,D = Spline(points)
PrintSpline(points,A,B,C,D)
```

Here is Wolfram's graphic illustration (sorry about the missing piece $4\leq{x}\leq4.5$):

[image]

You can change the characteristics of the "horizontal" parts by "playing" with the midpoint values.

Comment: Hmmm. That is interesting, but I would need a formal expression, mathematically manipulable, from which I can compute the derivatives, as other formal expressions. For an example of what I mean, see for instance the link I added in my question  http://math.arizona.edu/~shankar/projects/TermPaper_Yilu.pdf (pag. 10)

Comment: @Pam: Added a graphic illustration.

Comment: Hmm. Well, while interesting, I am not sure this is something I can use or I can derive from. I would need something that has a formal expression whose formal "structure" does not vary with the integer $j$. It should entirely be defined in term of $x$ and the constants $\epsilon$, $\alpha$ (or few more if necessary), but not "structurally" dependent on $j$.

Comment: @Pam: Well, from the look of it, I think it's fair to say that it does not depend on the value of $j$, as you have the same coefficients for every piece of the function in the range ${K}\leq{x}\leq{k+0.5}$ and the same coefficients for every piece of the function in the range ${K+0.5}\leq{x}\leq{k+1}$ You can observe that in the example given at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @barakmanos -- Is this curve monotone increasing?

Comment: @bubba: I believe so, although you'll need to calculate the derivative of each piece in order to make of that.

Comment: @barakmanos -- the derivative is $-1/5$ when $x=2$.

Comment: @bubba: Well, $2$ is an edge point so I wouldn't "count it in". But indeed, if the requirement for this function is to be increasing in all the domain, then it might indicate of other pieces (besides the "end-points") suffering the same problem. I have not asserted this for larger domains, so I can't really say...